# Opengl Rendering(textures) in secondary thread

Tags: c, multithreading, opengl, pthreads

I wish to render Textures using pthread library. Here is the function that I wish to render through thread that will update textures. Initially my textures are loaded through init functions and rendered by display function(both in primary thread).

```
void *moveMap(void *x)
{
printf("move called\n");
  tim.tv_sec = 0;
  tim.tv_nsec = 500000000;
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName[0]);

int index;   
  for(index=pathLength;index>=0;index--)
 {
    printf("Go %d %d\n", Path[index][0], Path[index][1]);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Path[index][0]*20, Path[index][1]*20, surface->w, surface->h, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
    display();       
  }        
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
   if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
   {
      pressedXCoord=x/20;
      pressedYCoord=y/20;
      printf("Pressed on %d %d\n",x/20,y/20);
   }
   if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_UP)
   {
      releasedXCoord=x/20;
      releasedYCoord=y/20;
      printf("Released on %d %d\n",x/20,y/20);
      findPath(pressedXCoord,pressedYCoord,releasedXCoord,releasedYCoord);
      if(pthread_create(&inc_x_thread, NULL, moveMap, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
      }
   }  
}
```

findpath function basically computes shortest path between two coordinates and function moveMap updates a texture through that path.When I call moveMap function without thread texture is updated as required but when called through thread it doesn't.

Comment: openGL doesn't do multithreading unless you jump through a lot of hoops

Comment: So what could be the solution to this problem? Is there any method through which mouse function called by glutMouseFunc could be controlled by thread.

Comment: Why do you want it to be in separate thread?

Comment: Becuase I want my mouse function to be active every time. The moment it enters moveMap I have to wait for it to finish.

Comment: Unless you're talking about some very enormous amounts, the only slow part in presented code is `display` on each iteration. Do you really need to redisplay after adding each fragment to texture, even if iteration interval isn't fixed? Everything else would be fast enough to be unnoticeable.

Comment: I did that because I am moving a block by using that. I want previous block to be removed and mapped to new coordinates. This gives an effect of moving. Thanks for replying anyways.

Comment: @MohitJain well I've written about fixed time interval for a reason. The way you've done it - movement speed will depend on frame rate, not time passed. You need to save movement information and perform step at fixed time intervals, and threads are only adding more problems to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL does not work well with multiple threads, it expects that all calls come from a single thread.

You can use a [glutIdleFunc](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node63.html) to let it to a bit of copying at a time:

```
void idleCopy(void){
    if(copyIndex==0)return;

    printf("Go %d %d\n", Path[copyIndex][0], Path[copyIndex][1]);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Path[copyIndex][0]*20, Path[copyIndex][1]*20, surface->w, surface->h, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
    glutPostRedisplay();    
    copyIndex--;
    if(copyIndex==0)glutIdleFunc(null);//disable callback

}
```

and in mouse():

```
if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_UP)
{
   releasedXCoord=x/20;
   releasedYCoord=y/20;
   printf("Released on %d %d\n",x/20,y/20);
   findPath(pressedXCoord,pressedYCoord,releasedXCoord,releasedYCoord);
   glutIdleFunc(&idleCopy);
}
```